# Sql Server data -> MySql + Django migration

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql-server, django, migration

I have an existing website built on ASP.NET + SQL SERVER. It should move to Django + mysql soon.

What is the best practice to create the new MySql DB? I would like to keep some Unique IDS because they affect the URLS that should remain the same after the transfer.

Also I want to avoid the option to inspect database with Django because many models will be changed somehow.

Comment: Django has a good article about this topic [Providing initial data for models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/initial-data/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this was my site I will follow this steps:

1. Create the new [CDM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conceptual_schema) (Conceptual Data Model) of the new database
2. Create [django models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/) that will catch with new CDM.
3. With [SSIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services), migrate SQL Server Database to MySQL. (Relax some restrictions and constraints if it is needed)
4. Add relaxed restrictions and constraints to new database (auto_increment columns).
5. Enjoy

Comment: Usualy I make a duplicate of old database into new database and then I fill new tables from duplicated tables. I explain: two steps: first step clone tables from SQL Server Database to My SQL Database. Second step: fill new MySQL tables from MySQL cloned tables, usualy with [Insert ... Select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html).

Comment: so the workflow you recommend is to clone all tables to mysql -> create the new tables using django syncdb ->  moving all data from original tables to new tables (django-auto-generated) using insert..select?

Comment: Yes! just this. This is for me a valid workflow. What do you thing about that? Notice that do you don't need a new SSIS project, you can use export wizard. Please, let me know about your progress!